# Ningx : How to filter request with a particular query parameter value?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-parameters

To securize my Wordpress site which is always under attacks, I try fo filter (ie. return 404) to all request that tries to upload the wp-config.php.
The requests are :

```
GET /wp-content/plugins/recent-backups/download-file.php?file_link=../../../wp-config.php
GET /wp-content/themes/parallelus-mingle/framework/utilities/download/getfile.php?file=../../../../../../wp-config.php
GET /wp-content/plugins/imdb-widget/pic.php?url=../../../wp-config.php
```

So I want to return 404 to every request that have a wp-config.php in one request parameter.
Do you think it is possible ?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test `$request_uri` for the entire URI including query string, or `$args` (aka `$query_string`) for the entire query string.

An `if` statement near the top of the `server` block should screen out all of the requests you want to ban.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~* wp-config\.php) { return 404; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. It's works but I wonder if it will ever works regarding the caution on the if. I have to say have it's not clear for me if the if will work or not: "if is evil" -> maybe its work, maybe not ?

Comment: The `return` is perfectly safe within an `if` block. I just cite the application note in case you need to adapt my answer.